# How to print something multiple times on different lines?

Tags: python

trying to print some symbols in a rectangle. So that when it executes the code the symbols will look like this:

```
    ****
    ****
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code you've written so far?

Comment: You can do things like `print(4 * '*')`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in range(2):
    print('***')
```

Works in both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: ty, been struggling for a while.

Comment: Please don't include comments (about the question or the downvotes) in your answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Fair enough